# Eureka get SelectableSection by tag

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I have this code:

```
    form +++= SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>("branch_section", selectionType: .MultipleSelection) { section in
        section.header = HeaderFooterView(title: "Branches")
    }

    for branch in sharedBranch.branchList {
        form.last! <<< ImageCheckRow<String>(branch.name){ row in
            row.title = branch.name
            row.baseValue = branch.id
            row.selectableValue = branch.name
            row.value = nil
        }
    }
```

but i can't get `selectedRows`, i tried:

```
    let branch_section = self.form.sectionByTag("branch_section") as? SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>
    print(branch_section)
    print(branch_section.selectedRows())
```

both prints `nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to use this

```
form +++= SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>("branch_section", selectionType: .MultipleSelection)
form.last!.header = HeaderFooterView(title: "Branches")
form.last!.tag  = "branch_section"
```

instead of

```
form +++= SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>("branch_section", selectionType: .MultipleSelection) { section in
    section.header = HeaderFooterView(title: "Branches")
}
```

then your code

```
let branch_section = self.form.sectionByTag("branch_section") as? SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>
print(branch_section)
print(branch_section.selectedRows())
```

will work as inteded, I hope this helps you